# Metric Space Proof - Analysis

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{C}([0, 1])$ be the set of all continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. For $f, g \in \mathcal{C}([0, 1])$, define $d(f, g) = \max|f(x) − g(x)|$.
Show that $d$ is a metric on $\mathcal{C}([0, 1])$.

Comment: What have you got so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I am trying to understand metric spaces and the axioms involved.. this is all new to me. I can see how d(f,g) is >= 0 (non-negative). I can see how it is symmetric but I dont know how to show triangle inequality..

Comment: For $(f,g,h) \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $x \in [0,1]$, note that :

$$ \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert \leq \vert f(x) - h(x) \vert + \vert h(x) - g(x) \vert.$$

which follows from the triangle inequality. It should help you prove that $d$ satisfies to the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks for that.. how do I show that |f(x) - g(x)|<=|f(x) - h(x)| + |h(x) - g(x)|

Comment: If you've proven the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}$, note $f(x) - g(x) = f(x)-h(x)+h(x)-g(x)$ and then use the triangle inequality for elements in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

If it is zero, functions are same, since they differ nowhere. Always positive otherwise. Triangle inequality comes from the triangle inequality in complex numbers by just putting max in front.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. I'm not quite clear on how to proove the triangle inequality still. And why do complex numbers come into it? I am just looking at R2.. thanks

Comment: I somehow saw C in there, but anyhow the numbers you have are a part of complex numbers ;)